# Redirection for logged in user asp.net

Tags: asp.net, authentication

In Register.aspx.cs i have that code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
       }
    }
```

So if user is logged in it's redirect to Default page in case that i don't want logged user see registration page. I use CreateUserWizard and i added **step** with basic info.

0 CreateUserWizard,
1 BasicInfoStep,
2 Complete

And now there is a problem, the redirection runs after step 1 (BasicInfoStep), not after step 2 (Complete).

How do I check and redirect logged user after step 2 (Complete)?

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not very sure about this but How about you do the redirection only if `IsPostBack == false` which would be the first hit on the page (other hits should be postbacks and you can redirect again after registration is complete).

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!IsPostBack && User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
    }
}
```